# Saving an array of WriteableBitmap to file

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, writeablebitmap

Is it possible to save an array of `WriteableBitmap` to a file on disk as a whole, and retrieve it as a whole too?

Comment: WinRT, WPF, Silverlight?

Comment: @Denis I am interested in WinRT but also WPF if you know about.

Answer (score 2):

You need to encode the output from WriteableBitmap into a recognised image format such as PNG or JPG before saving, otherwise it's just bytes in a file. Have a look at ImageTools (http://imagetools.codeplex.com/ ) which supports PNG, JPG, BMP and GIF formats. There's an example on saving an image to a file at http://imagetools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Write%20the%20content%20of%20a%20canvas%20to%20a%20file&referringTitle=Home.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve a byte array from WritableBitmap. And that array can be saved and read to file. Something like this;

```
WritableBitmap[] bitmaps;

// Compute total size of bitmaps in bytes + size of metadata headers
int totalSize = bitmaps.Sum(b => b.BackBufferStride * b.Height) + bitmaps.Length * 4;

var bitmapData = new byte[totalSize];

for (int i = 0, offset = 0; i < bitmaps.Length; i++)
{
    bitmaps[i].Lock();

    // Apppend header with bitmap size
    int size = bitmaps[i].BackBufferStride * bitmaps[i].Height;
    byte[] sizeBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(size);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(sizeBytes, 0, bitmapData, offset, 4);

    offset += 4;

    // Append bitmap content
    Marshal.Copy(bitmaps[i].BackBuffer, bitmapData, offset, size);

    offset += size;

    bitmaps[i].Unlock();
}

// Save bitmapDat to file.
```

And similar for reading from file.

**UPD**. Added headers with sizes of bitmaps. Without them it would be difficult to read separate bitmaps from single byte array.